# How to sync google photos to google drive or local desktop

Tags: sync, google-drive, google-sync, google-photos

Is it possible to sync or backup google photos to my local PC, now that google removed the photos->drive sync?

Any 3rd party software is also considerable...

Answer (score 2):

You CAN sync now, it's just a bit of work:

https://pypi.org/project/gphotos-sync/

Comment: Right now this is a link only answer and if that link changes, your answer will be rendered useless. Please include relevant information from the link in the answer body to improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can no longer automatically sync Google Photos to your local computer after they removed that feature in July 2019. The best you can do is to use https://takeout.google.com to download all your Google Photos in a zip file. But that is not an automatic sync.

Answer (score -1):

You can schedule a sync with https://www.multcloud.com/ 
Its a sync service to sync between clouds, and support from Google Photos to Google Drive